# Instantiate array of game commands in Java

Tags: java, arrays, instantiation

I am not sure how to instantiate this array. I need to instantiate it with "pickup", "drop", "help", "view", "quit"

```
private static Command[] gameCommands; //declared in class
gameCommands = new Command[]{}; //I have no idea how to do this
```

It needs to be done something like that. I have a constructor in another called called Command that has a setCommandName and getCommandName.

I'm sure this is fairly simple I'm just having troubles thinking of it.

Comment: Does the constructor for `Command` take an argument?

Answer (score 1):

```
Command[] gameCommands = {new Command("pickup"), new Command("drop")};
```

would instantiate it with two commands. YOu can put as many as you like in

You will need to add a constructor for Command such as

```
public Command(String name) {
    this.commandName = name;
}
```

Comment: You must write `gameCommands = new Command[] {new Command("pickup"), new Command("drop")}` or `Command[] gameCommands = {new Command("pickup"), new Command("drop")}`, but your proposition does not compile.

Comment: gameCommands = new Command[]{new Command("pickup"), new Command("drop")};

This removed the error. But is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your end comment. I thought you meant that yours would not compile either for some reason.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 gameCommands = new Command[] {new Command("pickup"), new Command("drop")};
```

or

```
 public static Command[] gameCommands = {new Command("pickup"), new Command("drop")}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to instantiate your Command array with value `"pickup"`, `"drop"` etc
for this first you have to create argument constructor in your Command Class like -

```
public Command(String name) {
    this.commandName = name;
}
```

and later you can initialize your array like -

```
Command[] `gameCommands` = {
    new Command("pickup"),
    new Command("drop"),
    new Command("help"),
    new Command("view"),
    new Command("quit")
};
```

Argument constructor is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an array of String like:

```
String[] commands = new String[]{ "pickup", "drop", "help", "view", "quit" };
```

If you want to use a class for the game commands, better use an enumeration like:

```
public enum Command { DROP, HELP, PICKUP, QUIT, VIEW }
```